# why the first two icons's line-height does not work in chrome?

Tags: html, css

it works fine here, but when  i move the code to separate html and css files,and run it in chrome browser, the first 2 icons get higher than the third ,like this  in the image:
[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43Agf.png)

and my question is : why the first two icons’s line-height does not work in chrome? and result in the first two icon is taller than the third icon, how to fix that? i just want to align the icons horizontally

```css
.box {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <div class="theme-bar"><a class="box"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i></a><a class="box"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a><a class="box"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i><span>3</span></a>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks all good to me, in chrome

Comment: in my chrome my icons can not  align horizontally ,it looks like what i post in the image above , the first two icon become higher than the third, did you paste my code directly or add some other things to it?

Comment: it seems that the first two icons's line-height specified in box class did not work, i am not sure, they just do not align horizontally in my chrome browser

Comment: I'm just running the snippet, it's all good there. Probably you have some extra css on your page that's also doing stuff. Look at the inspector and try to spot the differences. Or start with a barebone version and add other styles until it changes; then you know what's up

Comment: i 've watched the inspector for 2 hours , but still can not find out why the line-height of the first two icons specified in box class do not work......

Comment: Try if it still happens if you remove the `<span>3</span>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```css
.box {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.box i {
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="theme-bar"><a class="box"><i class="fas fa-globe"></i></a><a class="box"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a><a class="box"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i><span>3</span></a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the i element is set to inline-block by font awesome , and the 3 i element are all inline level, but why line-height do not work on them?

Comment: It is getting height of the text we used in span..if we remove text within the span then it takes equal height

Comment: because its a default tag i, which automatically gets line height 0.

Comment: but when I inspect the i element's fas class, it shows its line-height=1,not 0

Comment: i've got the reason , i just miss a line in the html ,    `<!DOCTYPE html>`,after add this line to the top of the html page , everything works fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

i think line-height not working because of float: left;

Try this:

```
.box {
    padding: 0 24px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```